# Lower bound of Rayleigh quotient involving eigenvalues of symmetric part

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is positive definite, and $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that
$$\frac{(v,Av)}{(v,v)}\ge \lambda_\min(M) > 0$$
where $M = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ (i.e. the symmetric part of $A$).

$A$ is invertible, so its eigenvectors form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus we can say $v = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i v_i$, where $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and the $v_i$ are the eigenvectors of $A$. I've shown that
$$\frac{(v,Av)}{(v,v)} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \lambda_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}$$

The problem is that I don't know how the eigenvalues of $M$ are related to $A$. If $A$ has real eigenvalues (which as pointed out in the comments we don't know), then
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \lambda_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2} \ge \lambda_\min(A) > 0$$
but that doesn't help much, since I don't know how to relate the eigenvalues of the two matrices.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by a matrix being positive definite? I thought this subsumed the matrix being symmetric, in which case $A=M$ and you have it. Otherwise, how do you know that the eigenvalues of $A$ are real?

Comment: I took this problem from an old exam, and sometimes they are a bit sloppy about the specifics, so I'll do my best to guess at what they want. Doesn't say anything about $A$ being symmetric, which makes sense, because otherwise $A=M$ which isn't very interesting. As for the eigenvalues, just says that $v^T A v > 0$ for all real $v$, which I took to mean positive definite. Maybe the should have put absolute values around the eigenvalues in the inequality? I agree that we don't have any reason to think that they are real, just nonzero.

Comment: Amending my last comment. We know that $\lambda_\min(M)$ is real and positive, because $M$ is symmetric and positive definite, but I made a mistake in the post, because we don't know that $\lambda_\min(A)$ is real (as you mentioned).